# VBA to Copy Paste based on 2 Parameter files

Tags: vba, excel

To All SMEs,
This is my first port here. I am working on a vba code from last couple of days. I am not very good in coding, hence I need some expert help to solve that.

I have total 3 excels:, (1) List_Of_Files. (2) PARAMETER_FILE and (3) Source File.

1. List_Of_Files contains list of excel file path (Column A) and
   corresponding Tab Names (Column B)
2. PARAMETER_FILE contains many tabs corresponding to each file/tab
   from List_Of_Files excel. Each tab contains cell reference of source
   files(from where to copy) and cell reference of target files(paste
   location).
3. Source File contains the data range to paste Now based on the above
   source file, need to create 1 new target file for each source file.

I am working on this from last couple of days and have constructed the below code. But I am unable to do the following things:

- to search if file exists and if exists then take the file name and
  corresponding tab name
- pass the file name and tab name to the next Sub

Below is my code. Please help me to resolve that. I have searched in google and in this site as well but couldn't get any solution.

```
Sub Test_File_Exist_FSO_Late_binding()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FilePath As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
 FilePath = " "

If FSO.FileExists(FilePath) = False Then
    MsgBox "file doesn't exist"
Else
    Call COPYCELL
End If
End Sub

Sub COPYCELL()    
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim x%

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

strParamFile = "C:\Users\rezaul.hasan\Desktop\Practice\PARAMETER_FILE.xlsx" 'this is the mapping excel
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\rezaul.hasan\Desktop\Practice\PARAMETER_FILE.xlsx"
Sheets("DIGITAL").Select
TargetFilename = Range("G2").Value
SourceFilename = Range("A2").Value
SourceTabName = Range("B2").Value

Set wbkt = Workbooks.Add
wbkt.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\rezaul.hasan\Desktop\Practice\" & TargetFilename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
wbkt.Close
strFirstFile = "C:\Users\rezaul.hasan\Desktop\Practice\" & SourceFilename & ".xlsx" 'Take the source excel
strSecondFile = "C:\Users\rezaul.hasan\Desktop\Practice\" & TargetFilename & ".xlsx" 'take the target excel

Set wbkM = Workbooks.Open(strParamFile)
Set sh1 = Sheets("DIGITAL")
lr = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To 4

Source = sh1.Range("C" & x).Value
Target1 = sh1.Range("E" & x).Value
Target2 = sh1.Range("F" & x).Value


Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
With wbkS.Sheets(SourceTabName)
   .Range(Source).Copy
End With


Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range(Target1, Target2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End With

wbk.Save
wbk.Close
wbkS.Close

Next

wbkM.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: it'd help you added data samples of you excel files. and detail where are you actually stuck in your current code (where does it run up to? what errors does it throws? ...)

Comment: Thanks for your response...I am stuck in the below two requirements:

Comment: to search if file exists and if exists then take the file name and corresponding tab name
•pass the file name and tab name to the COPYCELL Sub

Comment: FilePath is initialized to a space (`" "`), then your `Test_File_Exist_FSO_Late_binding()` sub is always returning the message "file doesn't exist", isn't it? Initialize `FilePath` to a _real_ path (like `"C:\Users\rezaul.hasan\Desktop\Practice\PARAMETER_FILE.xlsx"`). Then you must make your `COPYCELL() ` Sub able to accept arguments you want to pass it, like  `Sub COPYCELL(strParamFile  As String, tabName As String) ` and finally call it from `Test_File_Exist_FSO_Late_binding()` sub with `COPYCELL FilePath, tabName`, with `tabName` being a variable you have initialized to you tab name

Comment: sorry if i am making you confused. List_Of_Files has two columns - File name (Col A) and Tab name (Col B). My 1st code will take the 1st file name from List_Of_Files and will search in a particular path. If exists then will pass that file name (Col A) and corresponding Tab name (Col B) to the next Sub CopyCell. Once CopyCell sub completes then it will search for the 2nd file name in that particular path. This will go on till the last file name in the List_Of_Files